# Change the row while getting pasted from 1st row to fifth row

Tags: excel, vba

Here I am finding the last column in the sheet and copy pasting a column from one sheet to another.
It prints in the lcolumns but in 1st row i need to copy and gets pasted from 5th row.

```
Function Coletter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    Coletter = vArr
End Function

Sub Run_Macro()
     Dim lColumn As long
     Dim lColumns As long
     'Finding last column
     lColumn = Worksheets("Program Matrix").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
     lColumns = lColumn + 1
     MsgBox (lColumns)    

     Sheets("Output").Columns(60).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Columns(lColumns)

End Sub
```

**Sheets("Sheet 1").Columns(lColumns)**
Here lcolumns display the column number. But i need to get it printed from 5th row of the same column number(while it gets pasted from 1st row). How can i paste the same from 5th row.
Can someone pls guide in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't paste a whole column to row 5 (because it won't fit), so you need to shrink the copy area a little...

```vb
With Sheets("Output").Columns(60)
    .Resize(.Rows.Count-5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, lColumns)
End With
```